# Overlapping data and QQ plot

Tags: time-series, normal-distribution, qq-plot, overlapping-data

**Problem** [image]Have a time series of data and want to look at changes over long periods so want to use overlapping changes, then want to compare these overlapping changes to overlapping changes from a normal distribution in a QQ plot.

**Question**so far I have had to resort to creating overlapping data via Monte Carlo from a normal distribution to use as the comparison. Is there a more deterministic/better way to do this?

Example of overlapping changes - green cel is change made up of difference from two yellow cells. It is overlapping as there is one calculated for each day.

Comment: Could you please describe for us what "overlapping changes" and "overlapping data" are?  Perhaps you could give a small example.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Have edited and added an example. Hopefully that makes it clearer.

Comment: These are called "(lagged) differences." It would be unusual for your proposed analysis to yield much meaningful information--normality (or lack thereof) of these differences is typically way down on the list of things to examine.  What are you actually trying to learn from your time series?

Comment: Am looking at different amounts of lag and observing visually as increase the lag how much closer it gets to normality. At first I tried using the discretisation/plotting points as (n-0.5)/N but realised with lagged overlapping differences that even a normal distribution was not straight line if lag is large. Therefore I had to resort to using simulated overlapping lagged differences. Just hoping there was a better way than that.